# background color in Qt and opengl

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm implementing a simple 2D opengl class in qt 4.8 with QtCreator.
Nothing special, but I'm not able to set the background color oly one when I'm setting up the scene with glOrtho.

here is the code with some commented trials:

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include <iostream>

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent) {}


void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    std::cout << "GLWidget::initializeGL" << std::endl;
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height) {    
    std::cout << "GLWidget::resizeGL" << std::endl;

    makeCurrent();

    glViewport(0,0,(GLint)width, (GLint)height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height);

    glScalef(1, -1, 1);                 // invert Y axis so increasing Y goes down.
    glTranslatef(0, -height, 0);       // shift origin up to upper-left corner.

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    frameCount = 0;

    glClearColor(0.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //updateGL();   // this doesn't produce any changes
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    std::cout << "GLWidget::paintGL" << std::endl;

    makeCurrent();

//    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // this works but it is in paintGL
//    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

the fact is that i want to set the background color only once and all paintGL via updateGL each mouse movement WITHOUT cleaning the background. So the commented lines in the paintGL (that effectivly make the background green) has to keep commented.

For sure there is some update-something to call but I don't understan where..

Comment: By the way, there's no need for `makeCurrent` inside the reimpliemented virtual `...GL` methods. That's already done for you. And your `glScale` and `glTranslate` in order to make the screen coordinates Qt-compatible could be done much easier by simply using `glOrtho(0, width, height, 0)` isntead of your current `glOrtho` call (note the switched 3rd and 4th argument).

Comment: In the end this is not how OpenGL works. It doesn't in any way save what was once drawn to be easily redrawn. That's why you usually have to draw all things anew each frame (and that's in turn why you have to clear the framebuffer each frame). So the question actually is, what is it you want to achieve and which parts do you want to redraw in `paintGL` and which not?

Comment: OpenGL is a relativly low-level graphics API, so it doesn't have features like 'setBackgroundColor(...)'. If you want to be able to write code like that, you should use an engine such as [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/). When using OpenGL, expect a lack of higher-level game development oriented features. You'll have to implement those yourself.

Comment: hei, one moment. I want to draw a red dot on a white background without cleaning the background every time.. i don't this this is not opengl cup of tea

Comment: You don't. If you wan't a white background, redraw the whole background at each frame, and then your red point. Cleaning the buffer is a really fast operation, don't worry about that.

Comment: it is not for a velocity problem. is that i'd like to see the trail of the point. i can save all the positions and every frame redraw all them or.. i can avoid to clean the buffer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color only once, use initializeGL();

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1); //sets a red background
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() //countinous loop call
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //your code, paintGL() is looped continously to draw output.
    //hence setting background here is never good, may cause flickering.

}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (GLdouble)w/h, 0.01, 100.0);

}
```